# when I'm trying to install @angular-cli i'm getting the following warning

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-request

Getting these warnings while installing **@angular-cli**. Are these serious issues or is there something I'm missing?

```
   npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
   npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
   npm WARN deprecated debug@4.2.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error as warning while installing angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60737168/getting-error-as-warning-while-installing-angular-cli)

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

Hello Harsha Murupudi,

that comes from dependencies angluar-cli has itself. The only thing you can do is to keep your applications updated but even @angular/cli@11.0.6 has this old debug@4.2.0 as a dependency.

Checkout dependencies of angluar-cli by visiting: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli and click on: "Dependencies".