# Unable to install angular/cli, ng issue

Tags: angular

Could someone help me?

I am unable to install angular and I am not understanding my error:

```
> C:\Users\alear>npm i -g @angular/cli
>     npm WARN deprecated debug@4.2.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.
> (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
>     npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
>     npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
>     C:\Users\alear\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\alear\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
>     
>     > @angular/cli@11.0.5 postinstall C:\Users\alear\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
>     > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
>     
>     + @angular/cli@11.0.5
>     updated 1 package in 21.528s
>     
>     C:\Users\alear>ng new my-app
>     'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>     operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Does this answer you issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60737168/getting-error-as-warning-while-installing-angular-cli

Comment: Hi guys, I finally found the mistake, unbelievable but in my path in some cases my user was different, so ... I'd just format my laptop so I guess a problem that could solve properly

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

First update the version of `Node.js`. I find that the version `10.23.0` works the best. I recommend downloading that. Install that version and try to run `npm i -g @angular/cli`. This should help you solve the problem.

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v10.23.0/

Download the installer for your platform and re-reun the npm command to install angular and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Lakindu! My current node version is v14.15.3 and npm is 6.14.9

Comment: Try switching to 10.23 and see if it helps you out. I find that 10.23 is better for me when it came to angular